# I put an extra cup of water in my jello when making it. Is thete anything I can do to fix it?

Tags: gelatin

I put an extra ½ cup of cold water and an extra ½ cup of boiling water in when making my jello. Is there anything I can do to fix it so it will set?

Comment: If you have another box, you can make it up with 1c less water than it calls for, and then mix it in with the existing batch

Answer (score 3):

The only way it will set is by using more gelatin. You can use either more jello powder, or normal gelatin. You'll have to adjust the extra gelatin and extra liquid until the ratio is correct. If using pure gelatin, you'll need 4.5 g powder or three sheets for the extra cup of liquid; if using jello, calculate it from the instructions or add both a whole second box of jello and more water to add up to the amount for two boxes.

Even if you don't have jello or gelatin in your kitchen, you can keep the mixture in the fridge until you buy some more. It will set softly, but for making the final dessert, you can just re-melt it on the stove and use it as the liquid for the next batch.